# Are leads in lookup relationships still kept after conversion?

Tags: lookup, lead-conversion

If I have a lookup field with a lead in and later convert that lead, what happens to the value of the field?

I read somewhere that converted leads were only visible in reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in the field remains as long as the lead isn't deleted. When the user clicks on the lead name, when the lead has been converted, they are taken to a page that reads:

```
Converted Lead

This lead was converted on {ConvertedDate}.

Contact: {ConvertedContact.Name}
Account: {ConvertedAccount.Name}
Opportunity: {ConvertedOpportunity.Name}
```

The links to the contact, account, and opportunity are clickable, which will take you to the record the link points to.